# python simulate rock paper scissors

Tags: python, simulation

I want to write a function simul() that takes an integer and simulates n rounds of Rock,Paper,Scissors between Player1 and Player2. The player who wins the most rounds wins the n-round game, with ties possible.

Example:

> > > simul(1)
> > >       Player1
> > >
> > > simul(1)
> > >       Tie
> > >
> > > simul(100)
> > >       Player2

I've written:

```
def rps():   
 lst['R', 'P', 'S']
 p1=random.choice(lst)
 p2=random.choice(lst)
 if p1+p2=='RS' or p1+p2=='PR' or p1+p2=='SP':
      return '-1'
 elif p1+p2=='RP' or p1+p2=='PS' or p1+p2=='SR':
      return '1'
 else:
      return '0'

def simul(n):
 total=0
 for i in range(n):
      if rps()==-1:
           total+=-1
      elif rps()==1:
           total+=1
      else:
           total+=0
 if total<0:
      print('Player1')
 elif total==0:
      print('Tie')
 else:
      print('Player2')
```

When I run the simul() code, however, the only result I ever get is 'Tie'. How can I fix it??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python rock, paper, scissors game](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969772/python-rock-paper-scissors-game)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The only thing the two questions have in common is Rock Paper Scissors.

Comment: Start by adding some debugging lines. Where is your flow going, what does the rps call do, how many runs are you doing, why is it always returning tie: is it because rps() always returns '0' or is it because some other thing, etc etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `rps()` you are returning **strings**, but in the function `simul()` you are comparing the result of `rps()` with **integers**.

Since you are using `-1, 0 and 1`, you should return integers instead.

```
def rps():   
    lst['R', 'P', 'S']
    p1=random.choice(lst)
    p2=random.choice(lst)
    if p1+p2 == 'RS' or p1+p2 == 'PR' or p1+p2 == 'SP':
        return -1
    elif p1+p2 == 'RP' or p1+p2 == 'PS' or p1+p2 == 'SR':
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

**Note:** Python use `'single quotes'`, `"double quotes"` and `"""triple quotes"""` to recognize strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems. The first is that you're returning strings:

```
if p1+p2=='RS' or p1+p2=='PR' or p1+p2=='SP':
    return '-1'
elif p1+p2=='RP' or p1+p2=='PS' or p1+p2=='SR':
    return '1'
else:
    return '0'
```

but comparing the result with integers:

```
if rps()==-1:
    total+=-1
elif rps()==1:
    total+=1
else:
    total+=0
```

An integer is not considered equal to its textual representation. Return integers from `rps` instead of strings.

The second problem is that in `simul`, if the `rps()==-1` branch isn't taken, you simulate another round of play for the second check:

```
if rps()==-1:
    total+=-1
elif rps()==1:
    total+=1
```

Simulate one round per iteration of the loop, and use the result of that one round in both checks:

```
for i in range(n):
    result = rps()
    if result == -1:
        total += -1
    elif result == 1:
        total += 1
    else:
        total += 0
```