# Can Python's asyncio.coroutine be thought of as a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coroutine, python-asyncio

I googled `python coroutine`, and saw only generators (Almost almost all the examples use `yield` without `asyncio`.)

Are they really the same?

What is the difference between `asyncio.coroutine` and a generator?

Comment: This question is a bit broad right now. You might be better off editing it to just cover one or two specific points (perhaps related to what you want to do with `yieldFromRequests`?). I would recommend reading [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), which introduced `yield from` to the language, and [PEP 3156](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/), which introduced `asyncio`. Between those two documents most of your questions should be answered.

Comment: Also of interest might be [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492), which is a proposal to make the syntax for coroutines more distinct from the syntax for generators - which means no more using `yield from` to implement coroutines. The PEP hasn't been accepted yet, though it looks like it will be accepted some time soon (perhaps even in time for Python 3.5).

Comment: @dano I edited question. I post question separately.

Comment: The short answer is Yes. Here are two references: [David Beazley's Coroutine Presentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dabeaz.com%2Fcoroutines%2FCoroutines.pdf&ei=Qyo1VaHCA8amgwSrkIGAAQ&usg=AFQjCNE4C2E-kSH8E3D4jVcJFXClBmkKpg&sig2=gpJ3kubYAF82vmB6dQLebQ&bvm=bv.91071109,d.eXY) and a [Rock, Paper, Scissors Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969772/python-rock-paper-scissors-game).

Comment: This is an important question as this issue generates a lot of confusion. So while asyncio.corountines are technically generators, their application is really a whole other kettle of fish, and confusing the two approaches makes it much more difficult to learn or apply either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most coroutine implementations in Python (including those provided by `asyncio` and `tornado`) are implemented using generators. This has been the case since [PEP 342 - Coroutines via Enhanced Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) made it possible to send values into running generator objects, which enabled the implementation simple coroutines. Coroutines technically *are* generators, they're just designed to be used in a very different way. In fact, the PEP for `asyncio` [explicitly states this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3156/#coroutines):

> A coroutine is a generator that follows certain conventions.

`asyncio.coroutine` *is* a generator. Quite literally:

```
>>> import asyncio
>>> @asyncio.coroutine
... def mycoro():
...   yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
... 
>>> a = mycoro()
>>> a
<generator object mycoro at 0x7f494b5becf0>
```

The difference, again, is in how the two things are meant to be used. Trying to iterate over a `asyncio.coroutine` like an ordinary generator will not work:

```
>>> next(a)
Future<PENDING>
>>> next(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in mycoro
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 548, in sleep
    return (yield from future)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 349, in __iter__
    assert self.done(), "yield from wasn't used with future"
AssertionError: yield from wasn't used with future
```

Clearly, you're not meant to iterate over it. You're only meant to `yield from` it, or register it with the `asyncio` event loop using `asyncio.create_task` or `asyncio.async`.

As I mentioned earlier, it's been possible to implement coroutines using generators since PEP 342, which was long before `asyncio` or `yield from` came along; that feature was added back in 2005. `asyncio` and `yield from` just add features that make writing coroutines easier.